# Using Java 7-based learning materials when Java 8 is released?

Tags: java-7, java-8

Am an absolute beginner, trying to learn Java for quite some time but recently started serious studying.

My concern is that 90% of the books I have (dozens of books) are based on Java 7, I have two O'Reilly Java 8 guides but they are bridging materials, meaning I should already have vast knowledge of Java for them to be of any use to me.

To cut it short, would using Java 7-based books to learn Java be a problem now that Java 8 is released ? would I be missing something ? would it be easy to learn the new features in Java 8 later on ?

Note that newer versions of some of the books I have are in the making and are expected to be available by mid June.

Comment: At first, absolute beginners start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial and it does cover Java8. Second, Java7 is a basis for java8 and you can perfectly live with that and not to bother about Java8 at all, until you feel the defeciencies of Java 7. At last, you do not need other books to learn java.

Comment: For extra background. Even reading *Effective Java* (though being due for an update) is well worth reading it, and it is based on Java 5 or Java 6. You just have to be able to say for yourself that some techniques used in examples are obselete since Java 7 or Java 8. As recommended elsewhere, first start with all Oracle Java official trails.

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 is backward-compatible with Java 7 (and with all previous versions, BTW). The only important things you'll miss are the lambda support, the Stream API, and the new javax.time API, that were added in Java 8.

But everything you'll learn with Java 7 will still be completely relevant in Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, are those Java 8 features relevant for an absolute beginner like me ? Right now am thinking of just using the materials I have and hopefully after a couple of months fill the blanks.

Comment: Absolutely, they are relevant. You'll probably very soon have to parse, format and do soe computations with dates, and the new API is a huge improvement compared to what we had. And the lambda and the stream APIs help in day-to-day programming, when dealing with lists of objects, in order to filter them, sort them, transform them, etc. But most Java applications will probably not migrate to Java 8 before some time, and my guess is that most Java programmers haven't learnt Java 8 yet.

Comment: For basic java learning you don't need the java 8 features. You can learn them afterwards. They are helpfull but not nessessary and you can't use them if your Project is not running on java 8.